# Amazon Elastic Inference Client Library Logging

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, mxnet

I am using mxnet python library for using AWS EIA. When I am binding it with mx.mod.Module, I am getting these messages.

```
Using Amazon Elastic Inference Client Library Version: x.x.xx
Number of Elastic Inference Accelerators Available: x
Elastic Inference Accelerator ID: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Elastic Inference Accelerator Type: xxxxxxx
```

Could you please help me on when and where from these messages are coming?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is part of the EI-specific MXNet version available on AWS. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elastic-inference/latest/developerguide/ei-python.html for details.